# La expresión debe tener un valor constante c++

Tags: c++

**me tira un error en el arreglo *tan* char entrada[tan];**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tan = 255, cont = 0;
    char entrada[tan];
    //inicializamos el arreglo con espacios en blanco
    for (int i = 0; i<tan; i++)
        entrada[i] = ' ';

    cout << "Ingrese caracteres: ";
    cin.getline(entrada, tan);
    for (int i = 0; i<tan; i++)
        if (entrada[i] != ' ')
            cont++;

    cout << "La cantidad de caracteres: " << --cont;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar más sobre cuál es el resultado esperado? A mí me funciona bien así como está. (sin incluir `stdafx.h` obviamente).

    ➜  Desktop ./a.out 
    Ingrese caracteres: hola mundo
    La cantidad de caracteres: 9%

Comment: @akko trata de compilar el código dado por el OP con los flags `-Wall` y `-pedantic`. Notarás la diferencia.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando Visual Studio (lo cual parece por el uso de la cabecera `"stdafx.h"`), el código dado no te compilará a menos que cambies `int tan = 255;` a `const int tan = 255;`.

La razón es simple. En el estandar de C++ se especifica que los arreglos (arrays) deben tener un tamaño constante conocido en tiempo de compilación. Cuando tú defines `char entrada[tan];` estás creando lo que se conoce como un VLA (variable length array). Otros compiladores de C++, soportan dicho tipo de arreglos, pero el compilador de Visual Studio, siguiendo al estándar de C++, no los soporta. Es por eso que te sale el error mencionado.

Si quieres crear arreglos cuyo tamaño sea conocido en tiempo de ejecución puedes usar punteros o trabajar con contenedores que se "encarguen" de su tamaño, por ejemplo, puedes usar el contenedor `vector`.

Volviendo a tu ejercicio, este código debería funcionarte:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int tan = 255; //aquí hacemos uso de la palabra clave const
    int cont = 0;
    char entrada[tan];
    //inicializamos el arreglo con espacios en blanco
    for (int i = 0; i<tan; i++)
        entrada[i] = ' ';

    cout << "Ingrese caracteres: ";
    cin.getline(entrada, tan);
    for (int i = 0; i<tan; i++)
        if (entrada[i] != ' ')
            cont++;

    cout << "La cantidad de caracteres: " << --cont;
}
```

Más sobre `const` en este [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/const-cpp).